# Rotations through affine line (non-norm preserving)

Tags: linear-algebra

I wanted to check that if I want to use a matrix to describe a rotation through an affine line (a line that does not pass through the origin), it may not preserve norm, and hence is not an element of $SO(n)$.

My final goal is to show that if I have a set that's rotationally symmetric about two nonintersecting axes that do not meet, this set must be unbounded. Intuitively, this makes sense as I can imagine rotating around two axes that do not meet will increase the norm of the vector. But I'm not sure how to make this rigorous (I have very little understanding of lie algebras, and am also hoping for a (relatively) elementary solution).

EDIT: rephrasing my question with the aid of JBL's helpful comments (if I should delete the initial (poorly-phrased) question please let me know, as I'm unfamiliar with SE etiquette).

Suppose $A$ is a set that is rotationally symmetric across two nonintersecting axes $e_1=(1,0,\cdots,0)$ and $e_2=b+tv$, where $b \ne 0$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$. I want to show that $A$ must be unbounded.

My strategy is to show that that there exists $x \in A$ and a sequence of (non-linear) transformations $(T_n)$ obtained by rotating around the axes $e_1$ and $e_2$ such that $(||T_n(x)||)$ is an unbounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. This has already given me a new direction to think about, but other comments are also appreciated.

Comment: What do the words "use a matrix to describe a rotation through an affine line" mean?  (The usual identification between matrices and transformations is with linear transformations only.)

Comment: If I am rotating through the affine line $b+tv$ ($t\in \mathbb{R}$), then I would use the affine transformation $x \to b+U(x-b)$, where $U \in SO(n)$ represents rotation around the axis defined by $v$.

Comment: Ok, I see, it's just a red herring.  No non-linear affine transformation can preserve norms because they all send 0 to something other than 0.  Equivalently, non-linear affine transformations are precisely the ones where $b \neq 0$ (i.e., they are not represented by a matrix alone).

Comment: I see, so even if $0$ is not in my original set, by recentering the set and the axes I can guarantee the existence of some point whose norm is not preserved (in fact is strictly increased) by a non-linear affine transformation. Repeating this process inductively gives me a sequence of points in my set whose norm is strictly increasing?

Comment: Sorry, we are talking past each other.  I was still digesting your first sentence (having moved on from "use a matrix" to "it *may not* preserve norm").  Your big-picture strategy (start with a point, show that iterating the composition *eventually* increases the norm) is a good strategy.  However, it's not true that a single application of the composition strictly increases the norm of all points (it's a rigid transformation, after all).  It's also not true that "strictly increasing norm" implies "unbounded".  (Again I am not answering your question, I am helping you phrase it better.)

Comment: I have edited the initial question and am thinking more about it. Thanks for the clarification, and any other observations are also appreciated.

Comment: Rotations about an affine line preserve the length of vectors.

Comment: @Chris If the axes intersect, then $A$ can be bounded. For example, $A$ can simply be a sphere centered at the intersection of the axes

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank you for pointing this out, I've edited the question to only consider nonintersecting axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following procedure yields a suitable sequence of points. Let $L_1$ denote the first axis, and let $L_2$ denote the second. Let $x_0$ be the point on $L_1$ closest to $L_2$, and let $v$ be the vector orthogonal to both $L_1$ and $L_2$ such that $x_0 + v$ is a point on $L_2$. Let $P_1$ denote the plane with normal vector $v$ through $x_0$, and let $P_2$ denote the plane with normal vector $v$ through $x_0+v$.

I will refer to $v$ as the "upward" direction. A point $x \in \Bbb R^3$ will be "above" $L_1$ if the dot-product $d_1 = \langle x-x_0,v \rangle$ is positive and "below" if that quantity is negative. Similarly, $x$ is above $P_2$ if $d_2 = \langle x - (x_0+v),v \rangle$ is positive and below if that quantity is negative. Note the comparison between these two quantities:
$$
d_2(x) = \langle x-(x_0+v),v\rangle = \langle x-x_0,v\rangle - \langle v,v \rangle = 
d_1(x) - \|v\|^2.
$$

1. Start with any point $x_1 \in A$. Each point must be either above $P_1$ or below $P_2$. Without loss of generality (i.e. relabel $L_1,L_2$ if necessary), suppose $x_1$ is above $P_1$. Take $i = 1$.
2. Reflect $x_i$ across $P_1$ to get $x_{i+1}$. Note that $d_1(x_{i+1}) = -d(x_i)$, which means that $d_2(x_{i+1}) = -d_2(x_i) - 2\|v\|^2 < 0$
3. Reflect $x_{i+1}$ across $P_2$ to get $x_{i+2}$. Note that $d_2(x_{i+2}) = |d_2(x_{i+1})|$, which means that
   $$
   d_1(x_{i+2}) = |d_1(x_{i+1})| + 2\|v\|^2 = d_1(x_i) + 2\|v\|^2.
   $$
4. Repeat, starting at 2, taking $i \leftarrow (i+2)$.

I will leave it to you to verify that, although I defined this sequence using reflections, one could reflect a point $x$ about $P_1$ using a suitable rotation about $L_1$, and similarly one could reflect a point $x$ about $P_2$ using a suitable rotation about $L_2$. Because $|d_1(x_i)|$ grows without bound, we can deduce that this is an unbounded sequence.